# jQuery to output the user's city to their browser using the freegeoip.net API using AJAX and JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a question which am not sure I understand fully the question and the question says;

> Write Javascript or jQuery to output the user's city to their browser using the [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/) API using AJAX and JSONP.
>
> Hint: Use the endpoint http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=parseResponse

I figured out the question says:  *use that API to get the current location and display the city in the browser* and this is what I have done on jsFiddle and am able to get `City`:

jQuery

```
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#address").html("City: " + response.city);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

HTML

```
<hr/>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

Here is the thing, am not sure am doing what the question says. I will be glad if someone could shed more light into this.

Comment: looking for help on a homework assignment?

Comment: @happymacarts I solved it but am not sure I get exactly what am suppose to do. That's why I seek for clue.

Comment: what happens if there is not a city? should you include some logic to handle that? my response did not have a city Full response:
{
    "ip": "138.23.217.2",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "region_code": "CA",
    "region_name": "California",
    "city": "",
    "zip_code": "92521",
    "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "latitude": 33.7529,
    "longitude": -116.0556,
    "metro_code": 803
}

Comment: I suppose Yes. That could be factored in

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you have answered your required question.

you may want to consider adding some error catching in case the user response does not contain a city (mine didn't) also i added a snippet with Your response

```js
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    //add some conditional here to handle edge cases hint " use an if() "

    $("#address").html("City: " + response.city);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

Comment: What about the later part of the question that says: using AJAX and JSONP? Are you sure am on track? Ain't sure am on track.

Comment: perhaps ask your instructor

Comment: in my understanding if you are using the jquery.get function it is using an ajax call the address for the api is returning a json response, unless your instructor wants you to write out native javascript ajax call and not use jquery (they may want that) it looks like you have satisfied the assignment. If it were me i would clarify with the instructor or read any technologies requirements or restrictions